# Why is biblatex citing too many authors?

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to use `biblatex-chicago` to cite some papers with a common first author.  I am using `uniquelist=minyear`, so ideally biblatex should only display enough authors to disambiguate references that have a common publication year.  However, I'm finding that it's sometimes including **more** authors than are needed.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{Paper:2014,
title = {Title the first},
author = {A. Uthor and B. Buthor and C. Cuthor and D. Duthor and E. Euthor},
journal = {Journal name},
volume = {1},
pages = {1--10},
year = 2014
}

@article{Paper:2016,
  title={Title the second},
  author={A. Uthor and B. Buthor and G. Guthor and K. Kuthor},
  journal={Journal name},
  volume={2},
  pages={11--20},
  year=2016,
 }

@article{Paper:2016b,
title = {Title the third},
author = {A. Uthor and G. Guthor and K. Kuthor and B. Buthor},
journal = {Journal name},
volume = {3},
pages={21--30},
year = 2016
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
Here are three citations. \textcite{Paper:2016}, \textcite{Paper:2016b} and \textcite{Paper:2014}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the example, A. Uthor is the first author of three papers, one in 2014, and two in 2016.  The 2014 paper should be cited as

- Uthor et al. (2014)

while the 2016 papers should show the second author to disambiguate them

- Uthor, Buthor et al. (2016)
- Uthor, Guthor et al. (2016)

However, when I compile the above code, the three papers are cited as

- Uthor et al. (2014)
- Uthor, Buthor, Guthor, et al. (2016)
- Uthor, Guthor, et al. (2016)

The first is correct, as is the last.  However, the second reference seems to have added extra authors to disambiguate it from the 2014 reference.

What am I missing, or is this a bug in `biblatex`?

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/377

Answer (score 1):

This is a Biber bug (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/377) that was fixed in version 2.17.

The MWE now produces

[image: Here are three citations. Uthor, Buthor, et al. (2016), Uthor, Guthor, et al. (2016) and Uthor et al. (2014).]

as desired.